# Where is the default tmux.conf file located?

Tags: tmux

I want to copy the default tmux.conf file to my home directory, but I can't find the location in Ubuntu 12.04. The man page states that the file resides at /etc/tmux.conf however this does not match with my setup.

Comment: To find a file with name `<filename>` in a directory `<directoryname>` use the following command: `find <directory> -iname <filename>`.

Answer (score 85):

You can use the current (default) settings as a starting point:

```
tmux show -g | cat > ~/.tmux.conf
```

Note the pipe to cat is required for now because of a known bug when redirecting tmux stdout to file.

Comment: or `tmux show -g | sed 's/^/set-option -g /' > ~/.tmux.conf`: that would already prepend all the lines with a `set -g`

Comment: I got the error: no server running on /tmp/tmux-0/default

Comment: @RutgerH start tmux then detach session then do this command. I also saw this :D

Comment: You don't need `cat`. Just do `tmux show -g > ~/.tmux.conf`. Using `cat` like this is known as UUOC - "useless use of `cat`".

Comment: this doesn't return me anything, just quits back to the prompt...

Comment: @RutgerH I also ran into this, thinking the command was a normal terminal command. No, write tmux in the command prompt and then run the command.

Answer (score 22):

As per `dpkg -L tmux` which shows you what files the package installed, there is no default tmux.conf included in the package. `/etc/tmux.conf` is just a location that you may use (only makes sense with multiple users using tmux) that will be evaluated before ~/.tmux.conf. You have to create your own .conf file. Have a look at this for example (first hit on google):

[https://web.archive.org/web/20160308115847/http://dev.gentoo.org/~wired/conf/tmux.conf](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308115847/http://dev.gentoo.org/%7Ewired/conf/tmux.conf)

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /~wired/conf/tmux.conf was not found on this server.

Apache Server at dev.gentoo.org Port 443

Comment: @Kangarooo https://web.archive.org/web/20160308115847/http://dev.gentoo.org/~wired/conf/tmux.conf

Answer (score 12):

There is no default `/etc/tmux.conf` file. You can start with the example conf files in `/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples`, or look at the manual/web/etc. to come up with your own configuration file.

The `examples` directory contains:

```
/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/n-marriott.conf
/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/t-williams.conf
/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/vim-keys.conf
/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/h-boetes.conf
/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/screen-keys.conf
```

Answer (score 12):

The top answer's `tmux show -g | cat > ~/.tmux.conf` did not work for me since I got a bunch of `unknown command` errors.

Upon further digging it has to do with the syntax change so `tmux show -g` no longer generates valid config files. You must prepend every line with `set -g` in order for this to work or run:

```
tmux show -g | sed 's/^/set -g /' > ~/.tmux.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Even the command in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185291/158442) leaves syntax error in conf file.

```
/users/kube/.tmux.conf:35: bad key: none
```

I suggest below command:

```
tmux show -g | sed -e 's/^/set -g /' -e 's/prefix2 none/prefix2 C-a/g' > ~/.tmux.conf
```

This solves two problems

1. The syntax issue.
2. It allows to use extra bind-key <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> which
   is easy to type than <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

### Updated version of [Daniel (2013) answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/280587/288678)

> You can use the current (default) settings as a starting point:

```
tmux start \; show -g | sed -e 's/^/set -g /' -e > ~/.tmux.conf
```

### GNU screen compatibility

If you just need to add *GNU screen* compatible key prefix (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>) as described in [vijay's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1387092)

```
tmux start \; show -g | sed -e 's/^/set -g /' -e 's/prefix2 none/prefix2 C-a/i' > ~/.tmux.conf
```

### new location of the config

In current versions of Ubuntu you could also store the config file in `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`  [see tmux change log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES) **for version 3.1**

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/tmux/ ; tmux start \; show -g | sed -e 's/^/set -g /' -e 's/prefix2 none/prefix2 C-a/i' > ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf
```

### regarding Ubuntu 12.04

The original answer was this:

```
tmux show -g ; cat > ~/.tmux.conf
```

However Ubuntu 12.04 supposedly had tmux 1.7 ([citation needed](https://askubuntu.com/a/273018/288678)).  Therefor *"the list-keys format so that it shows the keys using actual tmux commands which should be able to be directly copied into the config file"* ( per [tmux change log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES)) has been added at least since tmux version 1.5 which means, that the above *original* command should not have been working in Ubuntu 12.04 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

#### improvements in this answer:

- incorporates [Alex H's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185291) using `set -g`
- circumvents issue with `no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default` error
- ignore case in `sed`
- alternative path `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf` (not Ubuntu 12)
- detailing the changelog-archaeology

##### Note:

I actually tried to edit the top answer, but it was rejected as it incorporates changes not present in the original answer.

Answer (score -3):

The config file is located in `/usr/share/tmux`, not in `/usr/share/doc/tmux`.

Comment: It seems nothing ever gets updated...