# How to install new tmux 1.8 on Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, ppa, compiling, tmux

Are there any PPA?

If no, how to make it from sources? Which dev libs I'll need to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**12.04 AND UP:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pi-rho/dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

As you possibly already realized, `tmux` version 1.8 is too new. As of writing this answer, version 1.8 is only [19 hours old](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/1b083aa0fd2d8ac000504488135bf58e35c3361e/tree/).

If you for some reason need a newest version, then you might download the code and build/install `tmux` by yourself. Should not be a big deal, since `tmux` has dependencies only on `libevent` and `ncurses` packages, and both of these packages are present on most if not all of Linux distros. Just download the latest code, and type following via terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libevent-dev libncurses-dev pkg-config
$ autoreconf -fis
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: ...you might also mention how you figured out which lib packages tmux would require to compile.

Comment: It's simple - these packages are mentioned on `tmux` homepage, right [here](http://tmux.sourceforge.net).  :)

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs The link you give for the official PPA is just the source package in Ubuntu - it is not a PPA at all.

Comment: what is 'autoreconf' - I don't have it. (Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: Those packages are not quite mentioned on tmux homepage. You have to know Linux to figure you need the '-dev' packages, and there's no indication as to whether you need libevent1 or 2.

Comment: To get 'autoreconf', use "sudo apt-get install dh-autoreconf"

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs it is indeed mentioned,but it could be a little more explained on their part :)

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, The `official PPA for tmux` you mentioned is not the ppa(binary archive), it's the source code of that packge.

Answer (score 33):

Here is the way I did it on Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) and 14.04 (Trusty Tahr):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pi-rho/dev` ([source](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/dev))

`sudo apt-get update` (freshens the cache/database of packages)

`sudo apt-cache show tmux` (*optional, shows you available versions, 1.7 & 1.8 should be listed)

`sudo apt-get install tmux`

`tmux -V`

Comment: I only get Version: 1.7-3 (amd64). May it be possible that those are only 32 bits packages?

Comment: Not sure, I am on 64bit if that helps.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Same as you, ubuntu 13.04... strange! Anyway, I finally installed it from the source. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear you got it installed. Yeah, that is strange.

Comment: This pi-rho fellow is fantastic. Packages are still maintained and up to date, even a year later. The PPA even supports 14.04. Thank you, whomever you are.

Answer (score 6):

I have not found an "official" PPA for new tmux packages.  However a [PPA search on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=tmux) turns up quite a few options.

Many are out of date, but I found a [ppa by pi-rho](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/dev) that has current tmux and tmux-next packages for 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04.  (At the time of this answer they are at versions 1.8-1ubuntu1~ppa2 and 1.9~20130425~bzr3062+9-1ubuntu1~ppa0).  There is no guarantee that that PPA will continue to be maintained up-to-date, but for now it seems like a fair option.

Be aware that it also has a number of other packages in it.  If you add this PPA you will find the other packages also get upgraded unless you do some sort of [apt pin config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170235/how-do-i-cherry-pick-packages-from-a-ppa/170265#170265).

Answer (score 5):

In order to run [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) on Ubuntu Precise (12.04), I needed tmux v1.8+, which is available in Saucy now and therefore in the "backports" repository for Precise. Here's how I got it:

1. Per [UbuntuBackports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports), edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to enable the "precise-backports" repositories (around line 45).
2. Update your repository cache with `sudo apt-get update`
3. Per [*different instructions*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository), install the backported version (1.8) with `sudo apt-get install -t precise-backports tmux`. I couldn't get `apt-get install tmux/precise-backports` to work for me.
4. Confirm the installed version with `tmux -V`
5. Happy tmuxing!

Note you'll have to kill all sessions and start with fresh ones, otherwise you'll get a server-client version mismatch error, and other users logged in on the same server may be running tmux, which will keep the server process alive until *everyone* exits. Look for zombies, too (`ps aux | grep tmux`).

Answer (score 1):

This PPA has it though, `ppa:kalakris/tmux`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me is to dpkg install the tmux 1.8 package built for Ubuntu 13.10 from the official PPA https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tmux, all its dependencies are met in Ubuntu 12.04.3

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar approach to rox, but I used the build for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) to get tmux 1.8 on my 12.04 system.

I downloaded [tmux_1.8-5_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tmux_1.8-5_amd64.deb) (or [tmux_1.8-5i386.db](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tmux_1.8-5_i386.deb)  for i386) from the Ubuntu tmux package page, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tmux.

Then, I used dpkg to install it:

```
 sudo dpkg -i tmux_1.8-5_amd64.deb
```

I did a clean restart of my system to make sure I didn't have any problems with server-client version mismatch, and so far everything is working fine.